# Creating self-signed certificates on iOS

Tags: ios5, ssl-certificate, self-signed

Is there a way to create self-signed certificate on IOS programatically?

We have a client-server connection, where the pairing is confirmed just once and then the certificate is used every time to re-establish connection.

right now we're doing it using openssl, but that is a little bit excessive for our needs. does ios have any mechanisms that would

- generate the x509 certificate
- apply it to socket (ergo create equivalent of SSL socket)
- query certificate sent by the server, so that it could be stored to verify server identity?

thank you!